# SVG that focuses on one area on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to update/add functionality for someone's library that displays a SVG. A demo of the library can be found here: https://rschristian.github.io/preact-github-calendar. Source here: https://github.com/rschristian/preact-github-calendar/blob/b51d41ac92d3b195e14a175248e4c408404830f4/src/index.tsx#L200 . It is (P)react, but the main thing is the SVG I've linked to (I believe).

So this library is a recreation of GitHub's contribution calendar, plus a few things here and there. Currently, the behavior is that the whole calendar is fit into the parent element no matter the screen size. So on bigger parents it scales up on smaller it scales down. The issue I'm trying to fix is that on smaller screens like a phone, fitting the full calendar into the width allowed really compresses the component and makes it rather unreadable.

So how does GitHub do this? It basically hides the left-most x%, so only the most recent (right side) data is shown.

But here's ultimately the problem I can't solve: I want the calendar to be remain dynamic (and I imagine the library's owner will too) but on smaller screens it should be cut off. I believe this means that I want to use the viewbox on desktop+ screens, but resort to height and width on smaller devices in order to actually cut it off. I'm not sure if this is the right idea though, and if it is, how to go about doing that at all.

Now I've tried a bunch of way of doing this, and I believe `preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMid slice"` is what I want (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) but I can't seem to get it working. I'm not really understanding how height/width, viewbox, and preserveAspectRatio all line up. It seems like preserveAspectRatio is entirely ignored and I'm not sure why.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-dubinsky-8miml

Comment: Would be good to create a small re-producible example of the svg code so we can focus on that

Comment: There is? I've provided a link to both the source and a running example.

Comment: Copy the code here into a sandbox that anyone can run and tweak is what I'm saying

Comment: Not a sandbox user, so no clue how the thing works, but I imported the same repo there. Hopefully that's what you had in mind.